# SQL Query to get top 1 values for each element in the list

Tags: sql-server-2005

[image]

I need help in writing a query which returns me all columns

```
select id, city, road1, road2, lat, long 
from tbltest 
group by id, city, lat, long.
```

The final result should have something like this[image]

Thanks, 
Pawan

Answer (score 2):

Although it is weird, that the table has duplicate id columns here is the query that would show the result you need:

```
select id, city, road1, road2, lat, long
from
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by id, city, lat, long order by road1, road2) RowNumber
    from tbltest 
) tt
where RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

```
;with tbl as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by id, city order by road1, road2) RowNumber
    from tbltest 
)

select * from tbl
where RowNumber = 1
```